# Can't import Android project into eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

I've cloned a project from git using sourcetree to a folder on my desktop. I open up eclipse sdk(workspace is another folder on my desktop) and try to import the project by going to Android->import existing Android projects, but the list of projects to import returns empty. Any help?

Comment: Try import local git repo instead. That's what I always do for pretty much identical situations and it has always worked for me.

Comment: Also make sure that you're looking in the right directory.

Comment: Doesn't work either, I'm afraid. I've tried general project, and that still doesn't work.

Comment: You are most probably trying to import the wrong direcotry. Can you specify the git project you downloaded (if it's public)?

Comment: It's private, but I'm sure it's the right directory. It has the res, src, and libs folders.

Comment: you can always try to "create new android project from existing sources" if the import doesn't work.

Comment: Try importing from the parent directory of the project directory. I mean one directory above the directory which has src and res folders. May be that helps.

Comment: You should try to use "Existing Android code into Workspace" instead of project